# Partitions of the Cantor space into parities

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, descriptive-set-theory

Call a partition of $2^\mathbb{N} = A\cup B$ a *parity partition* if, for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, flipping the $n$th bit of any element of $A$ results in an element of $B$, and vice-versa.

Given a choice function for the equivalence classes in $2^\mathbb{N} / E_0$ (where $x E_0 y$ if $x$ and $y$ agree on a tail) we can easily construct a parity partition; just let $x\in A$ if $x$ differs from the representative of its equivalence class by an even number of bits.

But we can do even better; given a nonprincipal ultrafilter $U$ over $\mathbb{N}$, define $$ x\in A \iff E(x) = \{n\;:\; x\upharpoonright (n+1) \mbox{ has an even number of ones}\}\in U $$  Then, if $x\in 2^\mathbb{N}$ and $y$ is the same as $x$ but with the $n$th bit flipped, we have $$ E(y)\cap [n,\infty) = (\mathbb{N}\setminus E(x))\cap [n,\infty) $$ so if $x$ were in $A$, we would have $E(x)\in U$, hence $E(y)\not\in U$, hence $y\in B$.

**Question**: Assume there is a parity partition.  Is there a nonprincipal ultrafilter over $\mathbb{N}$?

**Remarks**: (1) Obviously, this question only makes sense when working over ZF + some restriction of choice, like DC.

(2) One can show that the parts of a parity partition are neither Lebesgue measurable nor have the Baire property, so at least some choice is involved.

(3) There is an inverse to the function $E$ defined above, namely $ F : 2^\mathbb{N} \to 2^\mathbb{N} $ defined by $F(x)(0) = 1 - x(0)$ and $F(x)(n+1) = (x(n) + x(n+1)) \pmod{2}$ (after the usual identification of $2^\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$.)

(4) Here's the beginning of an attempt; suppose $2^\mathbb{N} = A\cup B$ is a parity partition, and without loss of generality say the sequence of all zeroes is in $A$.  Put $U = \{E(x)\;:\; x\in A\}$.  There are a couple properties of $U$ that we can prove;

(i) Notice that $E(x)$ is finite if and only if $x$ has a finite and odd number of $1$'s.  Since the sequence of all zeroes is in $A$, it follows that such an $x$ must be in $B$, or in other words; $U$ only contains infinite sets.

(ii) Suppose a set $S$ is not in $U$.  Let $x = F(S)$; then we must have $x\in B$.  Let $y$ be the same as $x$, with the $0$th bit flipped; then $y\in A$ and $E(y) = \mathbb{N}\setminus E(x) = \mathbb{N}\setminus S$.  Hence $U$ is "ultra".

However, it's not clear to me that $U$ is closed under finite intersections or taking supersets.

Comment: That's a nice question.

Comment: Paul, I hate intruding on someone's style, so I won't make this edit myself. But may I suggest that the definition of $A$  from $U$ will be in a single line of displayed formula (e.g. $x\in A\iff \ldots\in U$) rather than "some words, displayed formula, some more words".

Comment: @AsafKaragila, that's a good suggestion, thanks!

Comment: By the way, is there a clear reason why the definition of the partition from an ultrafilter doesn't work backwards?

Comment: Good question: I'll add another remark explaining what's clear and what's not clear in that strategy.

Comment: I think that if you show that $U$ is closed under finite intersection then it is a filter basis for an ultrafilter, so that should suffice. No?

Comment: Yes, or you could even show that for all $x,y\in A$ there is $z\in A$ such that $E(z) \subseteq E(x)\cap E(y)$.

Comment: Okay, so let $z=F(E(x)\cap E(y))$. If $z\in A$, we're done. Assume not, then in particular $E(z)$ is co-infinite. So perhaps we can find three integers, and $z'$ which is $z$ with those three bits flipped, such that $E(z')$ is still a subset of $E(x)\cap E(y)$ and $z'\in A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the answer was staring me in the face all along; since you can get a parity partition from either a nonprincipal ultrafilter or an $E_0$-selector, and the existence of just one of these objects does not imply the existence of the other (see [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/69615/axiom-of-choice-ultrafilter-vs-vitali-set) very interesting MO question), it follows that you can't get an ultrafilter or an $E_0$-selector just from a parity partition.

Comment: Well, non-measurable sets are non-measurable sets! :-)

Comment: The proper question, now, is whether or not we can identify partitions coming from principal ultrafilters. Suppose that there is one which is not coming from such an ultrafilter. Does this imply the disjunction "There is a free ultrafilter OR there is a selector for $E_0$"?

Comment: @Asaf, a principal ultrafilter won't produce a parity partition in the way illustrated above, since if $\{n\}\in U$ then flipping any bit past the $n$th one won't swap the elements of $A$ and $B$.